# Sequence convergence of positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\{a_j\}_j$ is a sequence of real numbers. Suppose for all $j$, $a_j \geq 0$ and the sequence $b_j = \frac{a_j}{1 + a_j}$ converges to $0$.

I wish to prove that $a_j$ converges to $0$.

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If $a_j$ does not converge to zero, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that infinitely often $a_j>\epsilon$. What does this mean for $b_j$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the assumption that $a_j \ge 0$.

$$a_j = \frac{1}{1-b_j} - 1$$ for sufficiently large $j$ (why sufficiently large?)

Comment: This is elegant, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Major hint: If $|b_j|<\epsilon$, then $a_j<\epsilon(1+a_j)$.  Consequently $a_j(1-\epsilon)<\epsilon$, so $a_j<\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$.